# Interleaving string with three or four strings

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have implemented the interleaving string problem with 2 strings using dynamic programming (with a 2D matrix) and now I want to do the same for 3 or 4 strings. I can't figure out how to manipulate the indexes. Can someone help me doing this with 3D or 4D matrix?

E.g:  s1 = one, s2 = simple, s3 = example, res = onsimexepleample -> TRUE

UPDATE** **Interleaving string problem:** Given three strings A, B and C. C is said to be interleaving A and B, if it contains all characters of A and B and order of all characters in individual strings is preserved.

**Implementation** for *two strings*:

```
public class Solution {
public boolean isInterleave(String s1, String s2, String s3) {
    if (s3.length() != s1.length() + s2.length()) {
        return false;
    }
    boolean dp[][] = new boolean[s1.length() + 1][s2.length() + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= s1.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= s2.length(); j++) {
            if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                dp[i][j] = true;
            } else if (i == 0) {
                dp[i][j] = dp[i][j - 1] && s2.charAt(j - 1) == s3.charAt(i + j - 1);
            } else if (j == 0) {
                dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j] && s1.charAt(i - 1) == s3.charAt(i + j - 1);
            } else {
                dp[i][j] = (dp[i - 1][j] && s1.charAt(i - 1) == s3.charAt(i + j - 1)) || (dp[i][j - 1] && s2.charAt(j - 1) == s3.charAt(i + j - 1));
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[s1.length()][s2.length()];
}
```

}

Comment: You haven't described what is `interleaving string problem`, and haven't shown your work with two strings yet

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I can think of O(n^3) and O(n^4) solution for three and four strings respectively.

Comment: @KaidulIslam, my fault. I thought about 3D or 4D matrix.

Comment: @MBo, I have edited my question.

Comment: @agoodguy So using 3D and 4D matrix will be okay?

Comment: @KaidulIslam, yes, sure.

Answer (score 1):

Okay Here is my Java implementation for three strings with 3D matrix memorization:

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean isInterleaving(int i, int j, int k, String s1, String s2, String s3, String S,
            boolean dp[][][], boolean visited[][][]) {

        if (i == s1.length() && j == s2.length() && k == s3.length()) {
            return true;
        }

        if(visited[i][j][k]) {
            return dp[i][j][k];
        }

        visited[i][j][k] = true;
        if (i < s1.length() && s1.charAt(i) == S.charAt(i + j + k)) {
            if (isInterleaving(i + 1, j, k, s1, s2, s3, S, dp, visited)) {
                return dp[i][j][k] = true;
            }
        }

        if (j < s2.length() && s2.charAt(j) == S.charAt(i + j + k)) {
            if (isInterleaving(i, j + 1, k, s1, s2, s3, S, dp, visited)) {
                return dp[i][j][k] = true;
            }
        }

        if (k < s3.length() && s3.charAt(k) == S.charAt(i + j + k)) {
            if (isInterleaving(i, j, k + 1, s1, s2, s3, S, dp, visited)) {
                return dp[i][j][k] = true;
            }
        }

        return dp[i][j][k] = false;
    }

    public boolean isInterleave(String s1, String s2, String s3, String S) {
        if (S.length() != s1.length() + s2.length() + s3.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        boolean dp[][][] = new boolean[s1.length() + 1][s2.length() + 1][s3.length() + 1];
        boolean visited[][][] = new boolean[s1.length() + 1][s2.length() + 1][s3.length() + 1];

        return isInterleaving(0, 0, 0, s1, s2, s3, S, dp, visited);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps! If you don't understand any part, I will put some explanation :)

Comment: Oh, that's nice. Thank you very much. I'll do it myself for 3 strings.

Comment: sorry, I clicked the wrong button. Anyway, this is not really working..

Comment: @agoodguy Hi, I am sorry for the buggy solution. Check the update now, I have write the correct solution now by modifying your Java one.